# i need to remove the current pictures when the user selects a new picture on the map

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
$(".select_picture").change(function(){
 var value;
 x=document.getElementById("choice").value; // get the value of the select option stores it in x
switch(x)
{
        case '0':                        //assign a case and the value, for my statement
            value=0;
            // alert(value);
            break;
        case '1':
                value=1;
                // alert(value);
            break;
        case '2':
                value=2;
                // alert(value);
            break;
        default: 
                value=null;
                // alert(value);
            break;
}

if(value!=null)                        //if the value select is not null it would execute
{
    //alert(value)
    $.getJSON('data'+value+'.js',function(items){              //gets the json coordinates from the file, data is the name plus the value and the type of file
        $.each(items,function(i,val){                           
            root=$(".root")                                     //created a handler on the div where the map is in the html file
            image=$("<img id='img'>").attr('src',imgs[value]).css({left:val[0],top:val[1]})     //
            root.append(image);
        })
    })
}
```

});

Comment: $(".select_picture").change(function(){
  var value;
  x=document.getElementById("choice").value; // get the value of the select option stores it in x
 switch(x)
 {
   case '0':                        //assign a case and the value, for my statement
    value=0;
    // alert(value);
    break;
   case '1':
     value=1;
     // alert(value);
    break;
   case '2':
     value=2;
     // alert(value);
    break;
   default: 
     value=null;
     // alert(value);
    break;
 }

Comment: Use `$(".root").empty()` inside `getJSON` success callback.

Comment: well the code works, basically it works when a user selects three options, mini pictures comes out on the map, my problem is how to delete the current picture when the user selects a new one

Comment: Have you tried my earlier comment ?

Comment: I got it to work your code help but I used $('.root').siblings().remove()

Comment: Great! Your code will work as well but slightly expensive operation as it will find all the siblings first and then will remove them by iteration..Mine is comparatively less expensive!